# Building operator image directly without operator-sdk?

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, operator-sdk

I had created my Kubernetes operator with the help of the [Operator SDK](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk)
Now I want to make some automatic build with my GitHub repo so when I push something to the master to trigger build of the operator image.

Can I use `go build + docker build` (for building the image) instead of the `operator-sdk build`?

Because if it is doing the same job I don't want to depend on one more tool for building the image.

I run `operator-sdk build` with `--verbose` and it looks like it is doing these only two thing (go build + docker build) but I am not sure. There could be some validations and checks before these command if I don't want to such validations exist I don't want to skip them.

Is a bad idea to use `go` and `docker` to directly build the image instead of `operator-sdk`? Because I don't want to do something special during the build I just want to not have one more dependency in the build infrastructure if it's possible to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar question and if you look at the source code for `operator-sdk`, it actually triggers `go build` and a `docker build` (the CLI, and not even the APIs for `docker build`). So yes, I wrote a simple docker file to do a `go build`. That's it.

EDIT: Here's the source for how the `docker build` command is formed and finally run as a system command: https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/blob/master/cmd/operator-sdk/build/cmd.go#L98